# .NET encryption techniques

Tags: .net, encryption

I am learning encryption in .NET. It seems there are 2 methods, symmetric:AES and asymmetric:RSA or DSA.

So in both above cases, when a user encrypts a message, does he use his private key and publish public key to the public so they can check the message? Please correct me if wrong.

Or does user hash the string, then encrypt with his private key? or public key?

**I am confused whether encryption in .NET is used as a means for authenticity of a message or actually encrypting the contents of the message**

Comment: Symmetric encryption = fast, therefore used for encrypting content. Asymmetric encryption = slow, therefore used to encrypt symmetric keys. (Via a key exchange.)

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with .NET. You just have the usual APIs to work with different encryption methods, but in the end, you're still using AES/RSA etc.

Comment: Signing is done with asymmetric keys. (Private to sign, public to verify signatures.) Asymmetric = slow and hashing = fast, we compute a hash over the content and sign the hash :)

Comment: does sender encrypt with his public key , then the receiver decrypts with their private key?

Comment: @Nash5655 it's the other way around

Comment: Ok sender encrypt using his private key. Then receiver can decrypt using the sender public key? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes that's the way asymmetric Encryption works.

Comment: Isnt it that the sender encrypts message using the receivers public key? SO only receiver can decrypt the message using receivers private key?

Comment: @dcastro Isnt it that the sender encrypts message using the receivers public key? SO only receiver can decrypt the message using receivers private key?

Answer (score 1):

Symmetric encryption algorithms use one key only, shared by both parties. Symmetric algorithms are faster at encrypting large amounts of data.

Asymmetric algorithms use two keys: one private used by the sender to encrypt a message, one public used by the recipient to decrypt it.

> Or does user hash the string, then encrypt with his private key? or public key?

This is called "signing", not "encrypting".
To sign a message, you usually hash it, and then "encrypt" the hash using an asymmetric private key. The recipient will then decrypt the signature using the sender's public key and obtain the sender's hash, hash the original message to obtain his own hash, and check whether the two hashes match.

Asymmetric algorithms are slower, but since the hash is a LOT smaller than the original message, speed is not a big issue.

Signing is a means of guaranteeing authenticity, it guarantees it hasn't been tampered with by a third party.

Comment: can you please give practical example